# Populate classes generated from XSD using XMLNode

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xsd, xmlnode, linq-to-xsd

I've used XSD2Code to create a set of C# classes representing an XML document I'm currently retrieving from a web service call.

The returned object of the web service call is of type XMLNode.

I want to create an object from the generated classes and then populate it from the XMLNode.

The outter most  class that seems to be have been generated is NewDataSet.

I'm a little stuck as to how to create/populate that object.
Do I need to use Deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up resolving this was as follows.

I used the project Linq to XSD Project:
http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/

Using the XSD I created a new set of C# Classes
From the command prompt

```
C:\Linq2XSD\linqtoxsd.2.0.2.56002-bin>LinqToXsd.exe vehicle.xsd
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version v4.0.30319]
Generated vehicle.cs...
```

I then imported this C# file into my code.

I had to add a reference to the Xml.Scheme.Linq library
I could then create a populated set of objects:

```
VehiclesData vehicleData = VehiclesData.Parse(vehiclesXMLNode.OuterXml);
```

and use Linq to access typed XML as follows:

```
string vehicleColour = vehicleData.DataArea.Vehicles.Vehicle.ColourCurrent;
```

and so forth!